# Query database for distinct values and aggregate data based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-values

I am trying to extract distinct items from a Postgres database pairing a column from a table with a column from another table based on a condition. Simplified version looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE photos
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  flag VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'John');

INSERT INTO photos VALUES (1001, 1, 'a');
INSERT INTO photos VALUES (1002, 1, 'b');
INSERT INTO photos VALUES (1003, 1, 'c');
INSERT INTO photos VALUES (1004, 2, 'a');
INSERT INTO photos VALUES (1004, 2, 'x');
```

What I need is to extract each user name, only once, and a flag value for each of them. The flag value should prioritize a specific one, let's say `b`. So, the result should look like:

```
Bob    b 
Alice  a
```

Where `Bob` owns a photo having the `b` flag, while `Alice` does not and `John` has no photos. For `Alice` the output for the flag value is not important (`a` or `x` would be just as good) as long as she owns no photo flagged `b`.

The closest thing I found were some self-join queries where the flag value would have been aggregated using `min()` or `max()`, but I am looking for a particular value, which is not first, nor last. Moreover, I found out that you can define your own aggregate functions, but I wonder if there is an easier way of conditioning the query in order to obtain the required data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method with aggregation:

```
select u.name,
       coalesce(max(flag) filter (where flag = 'b'),
                min(flag)
               ) as flag
from users u left join
     photos p
     on u.id = p.user_id
group by u.id, u.name;
```

That said, a more typical method would be a prioritization query.  Perhaps:

```
select distinct on (u.id) u.name, p.flag
from users u left join
     photos p
     on u.id = p.user_id
order by u.id, (p.flag = 'b') desc;
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! I have just learned two new things about SQL.